# Mellin transform of $x^p$ seems to miss a factor of $2\pi$

Tags: bugs, integral-transforms

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.3**

---

On Mathematica 11.1.1.0 the Mellin transform of $x^p$ is evaluated as $\delta(p+s)$, while I think it should be $2\pi\,\delta(p+s)$:

```
In:= MellinTransform[x^p, x, s, GenerateConditions -> True]  
Out:= DiracDelta[p + s]
```

---

*edited posting after Daniel Lichtblau's comment*

---

I initially did not understand this result, but [this 2004 paper](http://sci-gems.math.bas.bg/jspui/bitstream/10525/1235/1/fcaa-vol7-num4-2004-409p-420p.pdf) has explained to me how to arrive at the Dirac delta function, however, with an additional factor of $2\pi$. I checked that this is not a matter of a different definition of the Mellin transform. (I summarized the calculation in this [Mathoverflow posting.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/275047/11260))

---

*Missing factor $2\pi$ is fixed in Mathematica 11.3.0:*

```
 In:= MellinTransform[x^p, x, s, GenerateConditions -> True]  
 Out:= 2π DiracDelta[i(p + s)]
```

*consequence:* before 11.3 `Integrate[MellinTransform[1, x, s], {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]` returned 1, now it returns $2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(is)ds$
<sub>**Q:** is this v. 11.3 change in the implementation of `MellinTransform` documented somewhere?</sub>

Comment: See last example in documentation under Scope Elementary Functions. It should be noted that this is a generalization of the integral definition, not unlike the case for `FourierTransform`.

Comment: thank you, Daniel, for the feedback, I understand things a bit better now and have edited my posting accordingly --- my problem has been reduced to a missing factor $2\pi$...

Comment: What specific definition is used is not particularly important so long as the `MellinTransform` and `InverseMellinTransform` are inverses of each other. Both `x^p == InverseMellinTransform[
  MellinTransform[x^p, x, s], s, x]` and `DiracDelta[p + s] == MellinTransform[
  InverseMellinTransform[DiracDelta[p + s], s, x], x, s]` evaluate to `True`

Comment: @BobHanlon --- but if we assume that the factor of $2\pi$ is absorbed in the definition of DiracDelta, then `Integrate[MellinTransform[1, x, s], {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]` should return $2\pi$, while instead it returns 1.

Comment: The integral of `DiracDelta` should be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mellin transforms for $x^j$ reported by Mathematica 11.2 didn't make sense to me, so on 11/28/2017 I submitted the following question on Math StackExchange.

[Questions on Mellin Transform of $x^j$ and Interpretation of Distributions with Complex Arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2540541)

I ended up deriving the answer to my own question and on 12/7/2017 I submitted a problem report to Wolfram technical support where I attached a Mathematica notebook illustrating the problem and the correct solution (CASE:3980660).

I received an email from Wolfram technical support on 12/13/2017 indicating my analysis was accepted as correct and a report was being filed with the developers. The correct solution was subsequently implemented in Mathematica 11.3.

Note that not only was the $2\,\pi$ prefix missing, but $i$ was also missing in the $\delta$ function parameter.

I subsequently posted the correct solution in answers to related questions on both Math StackExchange and MathOverflow StackExchange.

[Delta function with imaginary argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2591712)

[Dirac Delta function with a complex argument](https://mathoverflow.net/q/294849)